# XCDYouTubeVideoPlayer opens and close

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've start working with `XCDYouTubeVideoPlayer`. It does seem to have, some small issues. When I use the method (like below) to call the player it opens it and close it right away.

I've imported following frameworks:
`mediaplayer` 
`AVfoundation`

and added the `XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController.h and .m

In the viewController.m I've added this method:

```
- (IBAction) play:(id)sender
{
[self.view endEditing:YES];
    NSString *link = @"m01MYOpbdIk";

XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController *videoPlayerViewController = [[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideoIdentifier:link];

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPlayerViewController];
}
```

At the moment its opening and closing the `XCDYouTubeVideoPlayer` right a way. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The problem in this line if u correct this then i hope it will help NSURL *videoInfoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=%@%@&ps=default&eurl=&gl=US&hl=%@", self.videoIdentifier ?: @"", elField, ApplicationLanguageIdentifier()]];

Comment: I found it, i'll try and look at this line to identify the problem. thx

Comment: You should just upgrade to the latest version of [XCDYouTubeKit](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit) (formerly XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController)

Answer (score 1):

I not understand why, but for me , in iOS8 the line

```
  XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController.m at #79
```

was calling the method :

```
 - (id) initWithContentURL:(NSURL *)contentURL
 {
      @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSGenericException reason:@"Use the   
        `   initWithVideoIdentifier:` method instead." userInfo:nil];
 }
```

I just comment it and works!

Answer (score 0):

XCDYouTubeVideoPlayer library build the youtube "streaming link", by appending the url with the signature provided. It seems that the "url" now has the signature along with it and the "sig" key comes null, which thereby negates the if statement in the function

> (NSURL *) videoURLWithData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error

Goto file

> XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController.m  at #248

you will see a for-loop

```
for (NSString *streamQuery in streamQueries)
{
   NSDictionary *stream = DictionaryWithQueryString(streamQuery, queryEncoding);
   NSString *type = stream[@"type"];
   NSString *urlString = stream[@"url"];
   NSString *signature = stream[@"sig"];
   if (urlString && signature && [AVURLAsset isPlayableExtendedMIMEType:type])
   {
     NSURL *streamURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString        
                                   stringWithFormat:@"%@&signature=%@", 
                                   urlString, 
                                   signature]];
     streamURLs[@([stream[@"itag"] integerValue])] = streamURL;
   }
```

change it to this (remove the signature variable from if statement and modify the URLWithString)

```
for (NSString *streamQuery in streamQueries)
{
   NSDictionary *stream = DictionaryWithQueryString(streamQuery, queryEncoding);
   NSString *type = stream[@"type"];
   NSString *urlString = stream[@"url"];
   if (urlString &&  [AVURLAsset isPlayableExtendedMIMEType:type])
   {
     NSURL *streamURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
     streamURLs[@([stream[@"itag"] integerValue])] = streamURL;
   }
```